# Get maximum date and corresponding row out of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

MariaDB Version: **10.1.40-MariaDB**

I have a 3 table Like A, B, C all three table have a column "update_date" and "update_emp_id". Now, I am trying to get max update_date with update_emp_id among all three Tables

for example Table "A"

```
+----+------+------+------+-------+
| id | update_date |update_emp_id |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | 2019-09-05  |  5117        |
|  2 | 2019-09-07  |  5118        |
|  3 | 2019-09-09  |  5117        |
|  4 | 2019-09-11  |  5118        |
|  5 | 2019-09-10  |  5119        |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
```

Table "B"

```
+----+------+------+------+-------+
| id | update_date |update_emp_id |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | 2019-09-08  |  5117        |
|  2 | 2019-09-07  |  5118        |
|  3 | 2019-09-10  |  5117        |
|  4 | 2019-09-15  |  5118        |
|  5 | 2019-09-10  |  5119        |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
```

Table "C"

```
+----+------+------+------+-------+
| id | update_date |update_emp_id  |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | 2019-09-06  |  5117        |
|  2 | 2019-09-16  |  5118        |
|  3 | 2019-09-09  |  5117        |
|  4 | 2019-09-12  |  5118        |
|  5 | 2019-09-10  |  5119        |
+----+------+------+------+-------+
```

Now I want To get max update_date with update_emp_id among all three Tables

Like update_date=2019-09-16 and update_emp_id=5118

Comment: can you add the sql query you have written so far ?

Comment: Not sure if your title matches your question and your question seems to state what you want, but not what you've tried.

Comment: If these are your 3 tables with the same structure, why aren't they 1 table?

Comment: Max `update_date` in table C is `2019-09-16`. Please check your sample data and the expected output.

Comment: ok my mistake so i want max date along with  emp id which has max date   like update_date=2019-09-16 and update_emp_id=5118

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the row corresponding to maximum `update_date` value in each table using `ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1`. Now, you can [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) results from all the table(s), and then again use `ORDER BY` to get the latest row out of all:

```sql
( SELECT update_emp_id, update_date FROM tableA 
  ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1 )

UNION

( SELECT update_emp_id, update_date FROM tableB 
  ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1 )

UNION

( SELECT update_emp_id, update_date FROM tableC 
  ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1 )

ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Result**

```
| update_emp_id | update_date |
| ------------- | ----------- |
| 5118          | 2019-09-16  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfSy93XAG1pJcETxSLTva7/0)

Comment: i want max update_date along with t update_emp_id  that has max update_date from all thee table    Like update_date=2019-09-15 and update_emp_id=5118

Comment: 10.1.40-MariaDB

Comment: Thanks its work but why we can use like this                                                   SELECT
  update_emp_id, 
  MAX(update_date) AS max_update_date
FROM 
( 
  SELECT update_emp_id, MAX(update_date) FROM Table A
  UNION
  SELECT update_emp_id, MAX(update_date) FROM Table B
  UNION
  SELECT update_emp_id, MAX(update_date)  FROM Table c
)

Comment: @karansharma because that will just get you the maximum `update_date`, but not the corresponding `update_emp_id`. MySQL can give you any random value there; in newer versions of MySQL, this query will return error because it is non-deterministic